# Change complete project namespace, assemblies, folders and references

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a big solution with about 250 projects.
I need to change the prefix of solution (my company name) from "X" to "Y".
Of course some of the projects' names start with the prefix - X.Utilties, X.Dal...
Means I should change project namespaces, assemblies, folders and references and even injection (IoC).
What is the best and safest easy way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I´d suggest getting the trial version of [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/) and using the available refactoring tools to change all namespaces.

From the top of my head you´d do it this way:

1. Manually edit your project files to have the new name (or do it with find/replace)
2. Reopen the solution in visual studio
3. Right click on the solution > Refactor > Adjust namespaces